# How to prevent an existing role being given permissions on a new database?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I'm fairly new to postgres permissions. I'm working with a postgres server to add/remove databases to it as part of a workflow. Each database needs to have a role associated with it that can do everything within that database, but nothing outside of it. I've got it working so far where I create a database and a role, and give the role (what I think are) the correct permissions. This seems to be working well.

This is the workflow:

- Create database A
- Create role A and limit its permissions to database A
- Create database B
- Create role B and limit its permissions to database B

However at the step when I create database B, role A is somehow being given permissions on database B. This means that when I later remove database A and its associated role A, I get an error because role A has objects that depend on it:

```
role "role A" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
Detail: 4 objects in database database B
```

In querying the `pg_catalog.pg_class` table in database B just after creating it, I can see that role A is in there:

```
{postgres=arwdDxt/postgres,"\"role a\"=arwdDxt/postgres"}
```

Any ideas what's going wrong, and more importantly how to prevent it?

--- EDIT ---

Here is the SQL I run to create the database and role:

```
CREATE ROLE roleA WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'password' NOINHERIT;
ALTER DATABASE databaseA OWNER TO roleA;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM roleA;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE databaseA FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO roleA;
```

I've tried various combinations of other permissions, but can't make it work with the permissions that I need. I've tried not doing the `REVOKE` and `GRANT` statements, but that also doesn't work.

Comment: That permission you see should only exist if granted *explicitly*. Something's not right here. Maybe [`DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) have been set somehow?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I get the behaviour on a brand new postgres server spun up in a docker container. I'm not doing anything with default privileges when creating the databases/roles.

Comment: "create role A and limit its permissions to database A"  If you just show us the command you ran, then we will know exactly what you did, and it might even be fewer characters too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this. As part of the workflow, I was running `pg_dump` to create a backup of a database, and then restoring it later. `pg_dump` was adding a `GRANT` command into the backup file for role A, causing it to gain privileges on the database B when it was restored.

By passing `--no-acl` to `pg_dump` when creating the backup, it no longer puts the `GRANT` in there and the problem is fixed.